# Good way to ensure multiple non-overlapping time ranges

Tags: javascript, datetime, logic

Through my searching I've found the following simple logic works really well for ensuring two time ranges don't overlap.

```
(StartA <= EndB) and (EndA >= StartB)
```

But it starts to get cumbersome (with my current approach) if I need to use many time ranges. Lots of If statements and such.

So what is a better approach? I've thought about filling arrays corresponding to 15 minute intervals of 'time' and running a check if those array places are 'occupied' when a new time range is added.

This will be using javascript, so I don't know if arrays are the most appropriate/lightweight however.

Answer (score 1):

A straightforward way would be to store the dates in an array, sort it by start date, then check if the dates overlap. Here's a sample:

```
var dates = [];
var addDate = function(start, end){
  dates.push({start: start, end: end});
};
var datesOverlap = function(){
  var i;
  dates.sort(function(a, b){ return a.start-b.start;});
  for(i=0; i<dates.length-1; i++){
    if(dates[i].end >= dates[i+1].start){
      return true; // dates overlap
    }
  }
  return false; // no dates overlap
};
```

Add all the dates you want to check with the `addDate` function. Then you'd call the `datesOverlap` function to check if any dates overlap.

Comment: Looks like a really lightweight solution too, thanks!